# Changing multiple ids on different pages at the same time

Tags: javascript

I want to write a code so i can change the text in my header on different pages at the same time.

I tried this JS code:

```
var text = 'Dummy text';
var weergave = document.getElementById('headertext');
weergave.textContent = text;
```

But this doesn't seem to work. 
The JS file and HTML file are correctly linked. Any thoughs on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you do any debugging? Have you checked the console? Are you sure `document.getElementById('headertext')` is actually returning the element you think it is? Etc.

Comment: share some effort what you did. whatever you've mentioned here is leading to nowhere.

Comment: `change [...] on different pages at the same time`: can you be more specific? If pages are loaded in different tabs or browsers, you can't achieve that by a js file. Or you need other technical stacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an `id` is always unique, you can't use `getElementById` to get all the `tags` with the given `id`. User `class` instaed of `id` and it will work using `getElementsByClassName`

You can use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById`.

And,use `class="headertext"` instead of `id ="headertext"`, in your `HTML`

```
var text = 'Dummy text';
var weergave = document.getElementsByClassName("headertext");

for(var i=0;i<weergave.length;i++){
    weergave[i].textContent = text;
}
```

Comment: Didn't even think about that.Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's showing on my homepage but not on otther pages. Any idea of way this is?

Comment: Glad i could help you. Please mark it as accepted answer if it worked for you. it might help others stuck in same problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

An `element`'s `id` must be unique, so you can not modify the `textContent` of many elements with a single `id`. You need to use a class name. You can use a query selector to get the specific elements that you need.

```
var text = 'Dummy text';
var weergave = document.querySelectorAll('.header');//gets all elements with a class of header
//for loop to get all the elements from the query selector
for(let i = 0; i < weergave.length; i++){
    weergave[i].textContent = text;
}
//or forEach
weergave.forEach(i => {
   i.textContent = text;
});
```

```html
<h1 class="header">Header</h1><br/>
<h1 class="header">Header</h1><br/>
<h1 class="header">Header</h1><br/>
<h1 class="header">Header</h1><br/>
<h1 class="header">Header</h1><br/>
<h1 class="header">Header</h1><br/>
<h1 class="header">Header</h1><br/>
<h1 class="header">Header</h1><br/>
<h1 class="header">Header</h1><br/>
<script>
var text = 'Dummy text';
    var weergave = document.querySelectorAll('.header');//gets all elements with a class of header
    //for loop to get all the elements from the query selector
    for(let i = 0; i < weergave.length; i++){
        weergave[i].textContent = text;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A little complicated for my level of experience but thank you! I will give it a try!